# FLUTTER Get access to an app feature only if you share the app

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, share

I made an app in flutter and it has special features. I want my users to be forced to share my app with their friend via email or messenger or any similar messaging app. I found the flutter_share package that could be suitable for the application (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share#-readme-tab-). 
But I am not sure how can I be sure when the user leaves the app he is going to share it? 
Can you help me with some demo app that has mentioned features?

Comment: You can only check if user clicked the share button, but there is no way to predict if he actually shared the app. You can however save user ID on your server and share the reference code, more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)

Comment: Thanks man. I'll use it!